# Can I find where a satellite image was taken in?

Tags: image, satellite, search, find

[image: picture of the place I want to find]

I really want to find where this is in because it was in my Math test and I've found a place like this before in another test but it actually had names around it so it was easier.

I know it's blurry but I want to know the furthest I can go.

Edit: I took the picture myself so reverse image searching wouldn't really help.

Comment: Ask the person who made the test

Comment: It was made by the ministry of education of Turkey

Comment: what about checking properties, it may have geographic coordinates of the center (if the image is taken by drone).

Comment: Just by the structure of pixels? No i don't think so. But would be a cool AI project... for someone with lots of money, time and skill... eventually? But seriously, if you do not have any metadata or georeference on your picture, chances are very very low. Its just luck in the end to find someone who maybe knows and recognizes the area.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. Add the image to a GIS and see where on the planet it draws.
2. Use something like [EXIFTools](https://exiftool.org/) to read and print the EXIF information.

See if there are coordinates associated with the image.